# All ports being blocked automatically in GCE VM

Tags: server-side, google-compute-engine

Google compute engine virtual machine ports getting auto blocked for sometime. and automatically opening sometime.
How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic) you can find the ports that are blocked on GCE by default. Besides the ports listed there, ports shouldn't get autoblocked unless you have some iptables rules that automatically block and unblock ports, which you'll be able to see with the command 'iptables -L -n'. Another possibility is you may have another owner/developer on the project that's modifying firewall rules on the VM instance's network.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, the way Google Compute works is slightly different than what you would expect. For example, the Compute firewall relies on the name of the network and the word "accept" to be in the rule name.

For example, if you network name is called "default" and you would like to create a rule for NRPE (Nagios/Icinga monitoring), you need to create a rule called "default-accept-nrpe" and then specify the internals to get it working - anything else just doesn't work.

What you are describing is the behavior of an Xinted service - that is being respawned too fast. For example, Xinetd will default to 50 connection attempts, from the same IP, per second. Now, if your client would connect faster, Xinetd will drop the service for 10 seconds, and will then resume the service operation.